# squid listen on out interface

Tags: networking, debian, proxy

I have a Debian box with squid3 installed on it. My box has 2 interfaces, one connected to the internet (`eth0`) and one connected to the LAN (`eth1`)

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.122.72.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.122.72.0
    broadcast 10.122.72.255
    gateway 10.122.72.1
    dns-nameservers 202.46.129.2
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.122.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.122.2.0
    broadcast 10.122.2.255
```

And here is some part of my `/etc/squid3/squid.conf`

```
http_port 8080
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl lan src 10.122.72.2 10.122.2.0/24
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow lan
```

With these configuration, I can browse on my local network (`10.122.2.0/24`) with Firefox by using http proxy `10.122.2.1` on port `8080`. For some reason, I want to make squid listen to both `10.122.2.1` and `10.122.72.2`. I have tried to change `http_port` directive to `http_port 10.122.72.2:8080` and set Firefox to use http proxy `10.122.72.2` on port `8080`, but Firefox said `the connection has timed out`.

Any ideas? Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

Might be a routing issue as you're (AFAICS) trying to connect from the internal network to the external network interface of your proxy. So your squid answers via eth1 since this is the preferred network device...

Have you tried this from a browser insode of 10.122.72.0/24